# iOS PortSIP Initialize failure ErrorCode = -60098

Tags: ios, portsip

I'm currently trying out PortSIP SDK for iOS to make a VoIP App. I'm not familiar with this error, anyone have an idea what this means?

Comment: take a look, maybe it helps https://www.portsip.com/docs/html_man/ios/html/_port_s_i_p_errors_8hxx_source.html#l00096

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error means "failed to create the network transport". Ensure the localSipPort which you passed into SDK which is not already used by other apps.

Try to test with portSIP parameters:

> Account1: UserName:507 Password:507 SIPServer:portsip.net
>   ServerPort:5060
>
> Account2: UserName:508 Password:508 SIPServer:portsip.net
>   ServerPort:5060

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if/how this relates to iOS, but on Android I learned that you also need to declare certain permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
```